# Rcpp returns large negative number when 2 large positives are multiplied

Tags: r, rcpp

I am creating a function that calculates area under the curve and when I take the 2 partials and multiply them for the numerator I exceed `2^31` and then a value like `-2013386137` is used in the calculation.

Here are the cpp chunks

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector sort_rcpp(NumericVector x) {
  std::vector<double> tmp = Rcpp::as< std::vector<double> > (x);
  std::sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
  return wrap(tmp);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector rank(NumericVector x) {
  return match(x, sort_rcpp(x));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double auc_(NumericVector actual, NumericVector predicted) {

  double n = actual.size();

  IntegerVector Ranks = rank(predicted);
  int NPos = sum(actual == 1);
  int NNeg = (actual.size() - NPos);

  int sumranks = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (actual[i] == 1){
      sumranks = sumranks + Ranks[i];
    }
  }

  double p1 = (sumranks - NPos*( NPos + 1 ) / 2);
  long double p2 = NPos*NNeg;

  double auc =  p1 / p2;
  return auc ;

}
```

and then the test example that has the issue

```
N = 100000
Actual = as.numeric(runif(N) > .65)
Predicted = as.numeric(runif(N))

actual = Actual
predicted = Predicted

auc_(Actual, Predicted)
```

I am also putting this in an R package

```
devtools::install_github("JackStat/ModelMetrics")

N = 100000
Actual = as.numeric(runif(N) > .65)
Predicted = as.numeric(runif(N))

actual = Actual
predicted = Predicted

ModelMetrics::auc(Actual, Predicted)
```

Comment: https://xkcd.com/571/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `int` internally in your function which leads to overflow.  Use a `double` and things look sunnier:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/jackstat.cpp")

R> N <- 100000

R> Actual <- as.numeric(runif(N) > .65)

R> Predicted <- as.numeric(runif(N))

R> auc1(Actual, Predicted)   # your function
[1] -0.558932

R> auc2(Actual, Predicted)   # my variant using double
[1] 0.499922
R>
```

The complete corrected file is below:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector sort_rcpp(NumericVector x) {
  std::vector<double> tmp = Rcpp::as< std::vector<double> > (x);
  std::sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
  return wrap(tmp);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector rank(NumericVector x) {
  return match(x, sort_rcpp(x));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double auc1(NumericVector actual, NumericVector predicted) {

  double n = actual.size();

  IntegerVector Ranks = rank(predicted);
  int NPos = sum(actual == 1);
  int NNeg = (actual.size() - NPos);

  int sumranks = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (actual[i] == 1){
      sumranks = sumranks + Ranks[i];
    }
  }

  double p1 = (sumranks - NPos*( NPos + 1 ) / 2);
  long double p2 = NPos*NNeg;

  double auc =  p1 / p2;
  return auc ;

}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double auc2(NumericVector actual, NumericVector predicted) {

  double n = actual.size();

  IntegerVector Ranks = rank(predicted);
  double NPos = sum(actual == 1);
  double NNeg = (actual.size() - NPos);

  double sumranks = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (actual[i] == 1){
      sumranks = sumranks + Ranks[i];
    }
  }

  double p1 = (sumranks - NPos*( NPos + 1 ) / 2);
  long double p2 = NPos*NNeg;

  double auc =  p1 / p2;
  return auc ;

}

/*** R
N <- 100000
Actual <- as.numeric(runif(N) > .65)
Predicted <- as.numeric(runif(N))

auc1(Actual, Predicted)
auc2(Actual, Predicted)
*/
```

Comment: Dirk, you are awesome!

Comment: Always a pleasure.  That was an easy one to fix but every so often we all have blinders on.  Been there, done that ...

Comment: I am building the package to learn how to use Rcpp and c++ in general so it is all new to me :)